# Lubuntu/LXDE - cannot open folder on desktop

Tags: lubuntu, directory, lxde

I'm running Lubuntu with LXDE. When I double-click on a folder on the desktop, it does not open. The read/write settings are correct. Any idea what I could do?

Comment: What exactly does it say, any kind of error window .

Comment: i have the same problem. and not for the first time. as the author of the question seems to have abandoned it and a new one will be a clone, I can but add more info here. Pcmanfm is in fact the issue here. Nautilus takes over the desktop against pcmanfm in Lubuntu in some cases. Any other problems with pcmanfm can entail the situation described here. After restarting pcmanfm or logout it disappears only to come back. PcmanFM has a certain instability. Reinstalling it would be a solution maybe... All serious problems with it I was able to solve only by reinstalling/upgrading the OS, until now

Comment: Ok so what version? Have you looked in launchpad? (the file-manager handling desktop icons is PCmanFM, the window manager is openbox) Have you updated from a previous version? -v

Comment: @turbo: i guess you're addressing me. what to look for in launchpad? i am in lubuntu 12.04, PCManFM 0.9.10. no updates. i blame nautilus for this, it has the habit of taking over the desktop. after uninstalling nautilus and restarting all ok for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling Nautilus if you have it installed and see if then it would work. Nautilus tends to take over the desktop sometimes in Lubuntu and Xubuntu, and even after recovering from this, certain problems like that reported may linger for some time.