# LXDE 18.04 LTS Lubuntu desktop keeps breaking

Tags: lubuntu, nautilus, lxde, pcmanfm, lxqt

Roughly once a day while I'm opening folders on LXDE at some point things break down. A folder freezes up and will not open. I'm prompted to cancel or end the process. Then everything on the desktop disappears. The only way I can continue to access stuff is by opening PcManFM directly. If I restart, the problem goes away, only to eventually re-emerge. In 2012, this same issue was [discussed on this forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158281/lubuntu-lxde-cannot-open-folder-on-desktop). Or at least, so it seems. One person suggested re-installing Nautilus, but apparently that is only a temporary fix. I am surprised that this is still a glitch 7 years later. Is there nothing that can be done to permanently resolve this issue? Is LXQt more stable in this regard?

Comment: Nautilus has never been part of Lubuntu. Both Lubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 are perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. You think the diagnosis from that 2012 thread is incorrect? If so, then what do you think is the cause of this problem, and how to fix?

Comment: As I wrote, I haven't experienced the problem you've reported. I haven't seen similar reports here or elsewhere either.

Comment: I use LXDE on top of stock Ubuntu. I get occasional (once or twice a week) hangs of PCManFM (that is in 12 hours a day / 7 days / week usage). The window freezes and I get the "not responding" popup. My desktop doesn't got away. I've been trying to find a possible trigger but haven't yet.  My best guess so far is that it happens when I do a lot of interactions with the window in a short time, but still have not confirmed that. Extremely unlikely (approaching zero probability) that it's Nautilus if you use stock Lubuntu.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yeah, it happen to me also, I wonder what causes that.

Comment: I also have the impression that the freeze occurs when there are a lot of interactions with folders in a short period of time, but because there seem to be some outliers to this pattern, I share Organic Marble's uncertainty.